# Slim Framework only works on local server

Tags: php, rest, iis, slim

I have an API that I have built and is running on an IIS server.  My web.config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="slim" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It may be worth noting that my structure is as follows:

```
wwwroot/
-web.config
-api/
--vendor
--src/
---index.php
```

I can access the API and make calls on my local server, and my entire API is functioning as expected...... the problem is that I cannot access from other machines on the network. The error message is that the site cannot be reached/refused to connect.   I have tried copying the web.config file to each directory to make sure that it is not an issue with where the file is located.  I have also created a dummy "hello world" php scrip and placed it on the server to make sure that the remote machines have access, and this is working just fine. (Accessing using http://myservername/helloworld.php)  It seems that I can remotely access anything that I place on the web server EXCEPT for my slim API routes.  Is there some configuration I need to set up in either SLIM or IIS to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is that the site cannot be reached/refused to connect

> Your rule seems fine. If your rule is wrong,you should ideally get 404
>   error and not "site cannot be reached/refused to connect" . This error
>   means the request cannot reach the server only.

You may be having a redirect in your application(e.g. to https) or you are accessing the website from other machine using incorrect hostname. Please check following

- verify the binding in IIS to make sure you are listneing on All unassigned IP address or the IpAddress of the server.  e.g. First binding

  `<bindings>
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />

       <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:hostname" />
    </bindings>`
- If you have a * in the IPAddress or a blank host name,you can access the site using http://servername or http://ipaddress from other machine.
- if you have a hostname given,you can only access the site using the hostname which may or may not work from different machine.
- if bindings are fine, Now capture a network trace from the IE developer toolbar or chrome and verify what exactly you are getting response.

Hope this helps!